# ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xdb80080)

Tags: perl, ubuntu, perl-module, cpanm

For some reason, whenever I run any Perl module (like cpanm), I've been getting this response:

```
ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got         
handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xdb80080)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. There doesn't seem to be any additional stacktrace, and even though there have been numerous bug reports and questions on this error, I was unable to find a solution. I'm running Ubuntu 17.04.

Edit: I'm running the default installation of Perl that ships with Ubuntu.

Comment: That means the `List::Util` on your system was built for a different version of perl. Are you using the standard Ubuntu perl? Have you tried reinstalling `libscalar-list-utils-perl`?

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, I'm running standard Perl that ships with Ubuntu. How would I reinstall that package?

Comment: I just started getting the same issue on macos 11.3. Trying to troubleshoot and posting my findings here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308565/mytop-on-big-sur-stopped-working-after-os-update

Answer (score 36):

This may happen when perl or perl modules are installed separately along side the official packages. Environment variable can be used to switch to a different perl installation.

To find out if that is the case run:

```
env | grep PERL
```

Having `PERL5LIB` or `PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` in the output might cause the issue. Try unsetting the environment variables and remove them from your `~/.bashrc` file or equivalent shell rc file.

Answer (score 5):

Derived from Bert Hekman, answered Jul 5 at 8:22:

```
env PERL5LIB= PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT= cpan
```

did the trick for me as a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: I manually removed `PERL5LIB` and `PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT` from my `~/.bashrc`, then reopen terminal and it worked for me.

Comment: Do you mean this maybe?

`export PERL5LIB= PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT= cpan`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out that a reboot did the trick. Guess I should have turned it off and on before I posted here.

Comment: I am running into the same case, differently, I have switched key value (got handshake key 0xdb80080, needed 0xde00080). And in my case, reboot can't solve it. My system is Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Using the above answers, I solved this problem. I had a copy of List::Util in my local perl folder.

I set the environment variables, then used cpan to update List::Util.

```
$ PERL5LIB= PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT= cpanm List::Util
--> Working on List::Util
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PE/PEVANS/Scalar-List-Utils-1.59.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Scalar-List-Utils-1.59 ... OK
Building and testing Scalar-List-Utils-1.59 ... OK
Successfully installed Scalar-List-Utils-1.59 (upgraded from 1.55)
1 distribution installed
```

I then no longer needed to use PERL5LIB= or PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=, I could just call my perl scripts as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS 13.6, after upgrading Homebrew perl, I encountered the same error. I install modules to local::lib to persist them across upgrades and the following gave the location of the offender:

```bash
$ find $( tr : ' ' <<<$PERL5LIB ) -path '*List*.pm'
.../lib/perl5/Test/Deep/ListMethods.pm
.../lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/List/Util/XS.pm
.../lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/List/Util.pm
```

After I run `rm -rf $PERL5LIB/darwin-thread-multi-2level`, I was able to run my scripts again.