# mytop on big sur stopped working after os update

Tags: perl, homebrew, macos-big-sur

After updating to macos big sur 11.3 (20E232) I can no longer launch `mytop` from the terminal.

When launching mytop - which is installed via brew - I get this error:

```
> mytop
ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xc500080, needed 0xc400080)

> which mytop
/usr/local/bin/mytop

> ls -la /usr/local/bin/mytop
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  33  9 Dec 10:24 /usr/local/bin/mytop -> ../Cellar/mytop/1.9.1_8/bin/mytop
```

So far to attempt to fix I have run:

```
brew update
xcode-select --install (wait 5 hours)
brew upgrade
brew remove mytop; brew install mytop
```

Still haven't resolved it.

I imagine this would a number of binaries. Has anyone seen similar and/or have a fix ?

Comment: Have also asked on the homebrew github discussion here : https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1381

Answer (score 5):

Solution : `brew reinstall -s mytop`

Details from [github conversation](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1381#discussioncomment-672466)

> This was caused by Big Sur 11.3 switching the default perl to 5.30. It used to be 5.28, and that's the version that mytop expects to find at /usr/bin/perl. See Homebrew/brew#10127.
>
> In the meantime, try brew reinstall -s mytop to rebuild mytop against the new version of system perl.

Comment: hmmm, something's fishy about that explanation. A prorgam that runs on 5.28 should have no problem running on 5.30.

Comment: If I had to guess based on the "handshake" part of the error message, something has explicitly declared that it will only work on Perl 5.28. Given homebrew compiles for macos and the perl version on mac has been pretty stable, I am not too surprised that someone would add that constraint ...

Comment: The message means that the loadable object for List::Util (which is normally bundled with perl) was compiled with one perl version, and is now being used by a different perl version.

Comment: It doesn't work for me:

$ brew reinstall -s mytop
patching file mytop
==> perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/usr/local/Cellar/mytop/1.9.1_8/libexec
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /Users/dutka/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mytop/02.make:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:220:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:221:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pageins;
        ^